# perl expect running 30 commands remotely

Tags: perl, expect

following loop does not produce the output IF I do not have the last exp->expect(5) line (kind of sleep). I guess this is because the loop is running 'too fast' for the 'sent' command to finish. How can i make sure the next command is run only when previous one is finished?  I am collecting output in log file.

any advice, pl.

ty.

```
use Expect;
...
...
foreach my $cmd (@cmd_array){
$exp->expect(3,
    [ qr/($|#)/ => sub { shift->send("$cmd");}]
       );
exp->expect(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `exp_continue` like-

```
use Expect;
...
...
foreach my $cmd (@cmd_array){
$exp->expect(3,
    [ qr/($|#)/ => sub { shift->send("$cmd\n");
                         exp_continue;}]
       );
}
```

Also, i think the statements inside `sub{...}` runs only if pattern matches as per `qr/($|#)/`. Also, I would think that after you type in an input or command you would generally press the return key to execute the command hence the `$cmd\n`.

Comment: $cmd has newline char in the end. so i do not need to supply another.

Comment: if i use exp_continue, it continuously runs the same command. I have to kill the unending loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just let Net::OpenSSH do this for you?

From its docs, you can use the capture() / capture2() methods
(depending on whether you need to capture just STDOUT or STDOUT and
STDERR from the process).

For example:

```
for my $command (@commands) {
    my $result = $ssh->capture($command);
}
```

I believe that should work, no?

(I've just tested this with a dead-simple script, and it worked fine for me.)

Comment: yes it can. but here user ssh in as someone else and then sudo to some other id, at that point you have to run expect.